# Android: how to use data passed from parent activity in a sub activity?

Tags: android

When we want to pass data from an activity to a sub activity we use the

```
intent.pushextra()
```

method and pass the request code and any additional data.

now in the subactivity how can I get the additional data or the request code.

is there any event handler that handles this ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `intent.putExtra()` to put data in the intent, then in the sub activity's `onCreate()` use `getIntent().getExtras()` or `getIntent().getXXXExtra()` methods.

For example for retrieving a String you would use: [getStringExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29)