# Receiving data which is passed using intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to receive a data which is passed using intent from another page.Can you help me?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130585/android-how-to-use-data-passed-from-parent-activity-in-a-sub-activity/3130603#3130603

Comment: to figure out what keys you have call keySet() on the passed bundle than

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an example

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
 Int ReceivedId = bundle.getInt("Id");
 String ReceivedTitle = bundle.getString("Title");
```