# Pass data from sub activity to parent activity

Tags: java, android

I've seen this thread: [Android: how to use data passed from parent activity in a sub activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130585/android-how-to-use-data-passed-from-parent-activity-in-a-sub-activity) and ready about this method, but I'm wondering if this is outdated.  Android has made a lot of strides since then and I don't want to do this the wrong way.

Is this still the method that should be used?

Answer (score 0):

This method is perfectly fine and is still used today. There is one more way in which you can pass the data using [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html).
Bundles can be used as follows

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);  
        Bundle b = new Bundle(); 
        b.putString("name", "abcd");
        b.putInt("value", 666);  
        //Add the set of extended data to the intent and start it
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
```

And in the other activity use

```
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    int value = b.getInt("value", 0);
    String name = b.getString("name");
```